# Problem with Boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers

I have a project with plate, pattern and brown cube and I am trying to make the bottom of the plate as the pattern an the top will be the cube color.
images:
[image]

Sorry about my English.
Thanks.

this is the file:
https://ufile.io/14990

Comment: So, what is the question exactly? If you are trying to apply colors and patterns to an object use materials and textures, not booleans

Comment: I want it will look like a woodturning project

Comment: That is probably a lot easier and faster to achieve with a wood pattern image texture instead ,unless you specifically need those independent geometry blocks. Booleans are well known to cause lots of trouble and generally yield bad geometry topology